# Screenshot with win32

Tags: python, python-3.x

The screenshots are being captured without problems, the problem is when running on machines with different resolution, or when the scaling adjustments in the Settings are at 150%.
The screenshots come out with 30% of the real screen.

Tested Windows 10 (1920 X 1080)(Scaling = 100%) Screenshot = 100%

Tested Windows 8.1 (1920 X 1080)(Scaling = 150%) Screenshot = 30%

Tested Windows 10 (1920 X 1080)(Scaling = 150%) Screenshot = 30%

```
import win32gui # screenshot
import win32ui # screenshot
import win32con # screenshot
import win32api # screenshot

def screenshot():

    # Identifying the main desktop window
    hdesktop = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()

    #determines the size of the monitors in pixels
    width = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN)
    height = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN)
    left = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN)
    top = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN)

    # DesktopContext
    desktop_dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hdesktop)
    img_dc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(desktop_dc)

    # Buffer of context
    mem_dc = img_dc.CreateCompatibleDC()

    # Create a image object
    screenshot = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    screenshot.CreateCompatibleBitmap(img_dc, width, height)
    mem_dc.SelectObject(screenshot)

    # copy the context of window
    mem_dc.BitBlt((0, 0), (width, height), img_dc, (left, top), win32con.SRCCOPY)

    # Save
    data_hoje = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%b-%d')
    relog = datetime.now().strftime('%Hh%Mm%Ss')
    screenshot.SaveBitmapFile(mem_dc, f".\\{data_hoje}\\{data_hoje}_{relog}.bmp")

    # releasing the processes
    mem_dc.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.DeleteObject(screenshot.GetHandle())
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the Width and the Height of `VirtualScreen` and those returned by the `GetMonitorInfo()` API are DPI Aware. But, Getting the DC and copying the screen using `BitBlt()` isn't. So, for a 1920x1080 screen at 125% scaling, Windows might return 1536x960 (maybe, it's just for an example). But, if you're using that with `BitBlt()` for a screenshot, you're merely capturing three-fourth of the screen.

Instead, The following approach works better:

1. Use `EnumDisplayMonitors()` to enumerate all the monitors connected to Windows
2. For Each Monitor you received (or if you want only one, get it using the array index) make a call to `GetMonitorInfoEX()`. Though this returns two fields `rcWork` (The Work Area, Resolution without taskbar) and `rcMonitor` (The Monitor Resolution), they are false. I mean they are again DPI Aware, you'll get the same result if you use this resolution
3. But, The Reason for calling `GetMonitorInfoEX()` is that you get the Monitor Name in the `szDevice` field. Now use this Monitor Name to call `EnumDisplaySettings()`. The Result of this call would return a `DEVMODE` structure. This contains two fields `dmPelsWidth` and `dmPelsHeight`, both of which represent the real resolution of the monitor in pixels.

There's an example of this (written in Rust) at [GitHub](https://github.com/candiedoperation/spifyrfb-v2/blob/2a905403c41af363a850e7989a0bd61d70856938/protocol/src/win32/mod.rs#L401)

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at pyautogui which is multiplatform. On my linux machine (120% fractional scaling) works flawlessly.

```
import pyautogui

shot = pyautogui.screenshot()
shot.save("screenshot.png")
```